# Inequality of logarithm

Tags: inequality

Given that the probability distribution is:

\begin{equation*}
X \sim 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & \dots & x_N \\
p_1 & p_2 & p_3 & \dots & p_N \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

with $p_1 \leq p_2 \leq \dots \leq p_N$. Prove that:

$$ -\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i\log_2 p_i \geq 2(1-p_N) $$

The hint in the exercice is to use
$$ -\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i\ln p_i \geq (1-p_N)  $$

for $p_N \geq 0.5$, and

$$-\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i\log_2 p_i \geq -\log_2p_N $$

for $p_N \leq 0.5$. But I didn't understood very well this hint.

Comment: What is the matrix notation? Does it describe the probability of each element?

Comment: Is this saying that $\sum_{i=1}^N p_i=1$? Or are the $p_i$ supposed to be primes?

Comment: Is this a Dirichlet distribution notation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

Comment: I edit the post, its a PMF